# How to sum values in Reporting Services via Visual Studio 2008 Expression Designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, designer, expression

I have a report like this

```
person | lead count | support count | ...
p1     | 10         | 20            | ...
p2     | 20         | 30            | ...
```

I need to have sum of counts in one column. I've tried this expression:
`=Sum(IIf(ISNOTHING(Fields!lead_count.Value) Or Fields!lead_count.Value = "", 0, Fields!lead_count.Value))`

but it gives me `#Error`, aswell as trying:
`=Sum(IIf(ISNOTHING(Fields!lead_count.Value) Or Fields!lead_count.Value = "", 0, Int(Fields!lead_count.Value)))`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how to get proper sum of counts (30 for lead, 50 for support)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the SUM directly:

```
=Sum(Fields!lead_count.Value)
```

No need to check blank values.